# Program to open multiple programs and change the options and setting?

Tags: batch-file

I'd need a program with which I could make a program where the user just has to click on an Icon which then starts up different programs, sometimes in a specific order, and then goes into the settings, tools and options and changes ports and IPs, for example - things which you'd normally use your mouse and keyboard to click around and do.

I was recommended to test batch files, but it seems, at least at this point, like I can't get into the programs' options and make the changes, just open them.

Is there such a program available with which I could do this and if so, which would be recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), a BASIC-like scripting language designed to do exactly the kind of things you are asking.

There is also [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) available, I've never used it, but this is also a tool designed to accomplish automated GUI-related tasks.

Comment: Thank you! Been checking tutorials and I would say that this will solve my problems.